# JS Moving particles on background

Tags: javascript, particles

Ive made a website and would now like to "spicy it up" a little with some moving elements.

Ive fallen in love with the subtle "bubbles" from Discord's website:
https://discordapp.com/

Can this effect be replicated with javascript without a massive hassle, and if so then how? Thanks.

Comment: They use divs in absolute positions with a css animation on opacity and others (transformY). Each div has a background-image. They do it in js.

Comment: Take a look at http://codepen.io/saransh/pen/BKJun Do consider CPU usage on mobile devices.

Comment: @AndreM CPU usage is not a concern since I will have a dedicated page for mobile devices without all the fancy effects ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try d3 js.
You can achieve almost anything you want with only js.

You can check the [gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) for examples.

Comment: I'd say it's overkill if he just needs that effect.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I thought it would help him with more complex problems.